# Is it possible to build an app that blocks or filters bluetooth signal while bluetooth on your phone is ON?

Tags: swift, android-activity, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We can choose which wifi signal to connect.

Likewise can an app provide a list of bluetooth signals for us to choose from?

Or at the least block all bluetooth signals except the ones you gave permissions?

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: You can't do this on iOS

Comment: With BLE you can scan which BLE device to connect yes, with normal Bluetooth you can do discovery to find available devices to connect to.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is what device pairing is. By pairing with a device, that device is added to a whitelist of Bluetooth devices the phone can connect to. Keep in mind that Wifi is providing a generic service access where Bluetooth is providing specific device access. The differences are subtle yet important.